# Help understanding movement script

Tags: unity, c#, movement

Can someone clearly explain how this script works and how I would be able to improve it? (It's a movement script)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rg2d;
    public float movespeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rg2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        movespeed = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float X = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
 
        if (X != 0)
        {
            rg2d.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed * X, rg2d.velocity.y);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you understand about this script so far? Are there particular parts about it that you find confusing that we can focus on explaining? What specific improvements do you want to make, or what problems does it have that you want tips on solving?

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, anyway the problem i wanted to fix was that my character was kinda slippery (someone else helped me fix it) and i got most of the code from a tutorial so i didnt realy understand it.(someone else explained it clearly).Again thanks for answering and i will try to make my question more specific next time.(i apologise if my english is bad its not my native language)

Comment: Explaining your issue in broken English is usually better than not describing it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I commented on every line explaining what it does. As for improving it all depends on what you want to do with this movement code and is a much broader questions.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rg2d; // This creates a reference to a RigidBody2d type 
    public float movespeed; // this is a variable that stores the movement speed
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rg2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();// this tries to get the RigidBody2D component that is on the same game object as the scipt
                                           // if no rigidbody is found it will return null
        movespeed = 10f;// this sets the movement speed variable to 10.
                        // NOTE that this will override any value you set in the inspector when you start your game
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float X = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // this will store the RAW, meaning unsmoothed value, of the axis defined as Horizontal into the variable X
                                                  // if you do not plan on doing smooting yourself I suggest using Input.GetAxis

        if (X != 0) // checks if the value of X is different than 0 and if it is we proceed into the if body
        {
            rg2d.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed * X, rg2d.velocity.y); // this line creates a new Vector 2 where the X component is the value our input times the movement speed
                                                                         //and the Y component is the current Y velocity of the rigid body
                                                                         //it also sets this new Vector2 as the current velocity of the rigidbody

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks a bunch  it really helped, i kinda understand how the script works now. the way u explained it was awesome .it helped me fix the problem i was struggling with (again thanks a bunch). also i apologise for my bad english.